# pointers in matrix multiplication not working

Tags: c++

```
class mm
{
    public :
    static int** multiPlyMatrix(int** matrix1, int** matrix2,int r1,int c1,int r2,int c2) {
    int** multiplication;

    if (c1==r2)
    {
    multiplication=new int*[r1];
    for (int row = 0; row < r1; row++)
    {
        multiplication[row]=new int[c2];

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex <c2; colIndex++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <r2; col++)
            {
                multiplication[row][colIndex] = multiplication[row][colIndex] + matrix1[row][col] * matrix2[col][colIndex];
            }
        }
    }
    }else
    {
           cout<<"Multiplication Not Possible"<<endl;
    }
        return multiplication;
    }

    static void deleteMemory(int** array,int rows)
    {
        if(array)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            {
                if(array[i])
                {
                    delete[]array[i];
                }
            }
            delete[] array;
        }
    }
};
void main()
{
    mm obj;
    int r,c;
    char ch;
    int rows,cols,rows2,cols2;
    int** matrix1;
    int** matrix2;
    int** result;
    do{
     rows=0,cols=0,rows2=0,cols2=0;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter number of rows:";
    cin>>rows;
    cout<<"Enter number of columns:";
    cin>>cols;
    matrix1=new int* [rows];
    cout<<"Enter Elements in Matrix 1:"<<endl;
    for ( r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        matrix1[r]=new int[cols];
        for ( c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
         cin>>matrix1[r][c];
        }
    }

    cout<<"Enter number of rows:";
    cin>>rows2;
    cout<<"Enter number of columns:";
    cin>>cols2;
    matrix2=new int* [rows2];
    cout<<"Enter Elements in matrix2:"<<endl;
    for ( r = 0; r < rows2; r++)
    {
        matrix2[r]=new int[cols2];
        for ( c = 0; c < cols2; c++)
        {
        cin>>matrix2[r][c];
        }
    }
    result=obj.multiPlyMatrix(matrix1, matrix2,rows,cols,rows2,cols2);

    cout<<"Multiplication of matrix:"<<endl;

    for ( r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        cout<<"|";
        for ( c = 0; c < cols2; c++)
        {
         cout<<result[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout<<"|"<<endl;
    }

    obj.deleteMemory(matrix1,rows);
    obj.deleteMemory(matrix2,rows2);
    obj.deleteMemory(result,rows);
    cout<<"\nWanna Enter Again?(y/n):";
    cin>>ch;
    }while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');
}
```

So, thats full code, program works perfectly for first run but when i run it second time it gives garbage value as output, when i exit IDE and open it again it will run great for first time then again it will give garbage value, 
what am I doing wrong?

I think theres some problem with delete method and I use turbo c++ as IDE and gcc compiler

Comment: C doesn't have classes; this cannot be C code.

Comment: and `void main()` signature of `main` function is deprecated.

Comment: Returning an uninitialized pointer when the matrices are not compatible is not exactly good news, is it?  This might be a point at which throwing an exception is sensible.

Comment: Also, you define a variable `obj` of type `mm` (`class mm`), but there really isn't a need since the two functions are both static.  You could simply call them directly (`mm::multiPlyMatrix(…)`, I believe).  Indeed, it isn't clear that the class provides much benefit; it does, just about, give a namespace around the two functions, but there are namespaces for doing that job. You could use a few more functions too; the code to read a matrix is a horrid repeat. Maybe `class mm` should be used to encapsulate a matrix, with the size stored in the class, and the double pointer, and a destructor.

Comment: *and I use turbo c++ as IDE*.  Please, don't.  *and gcc compiler* -- Much better.  Turbo C++ is 25 years old, is outdated, and doesn't reflect the state of C++ as it has stood since 1998.  The g++ compiler, depending on the version you're using, is up-to-date.

Comment: Yes sir, I will update compiler and does it mean i have to initialize my arrays to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect `multiplication[row][colIndex]` to be the first time the line of code using it gets hit?  (Just to be perfectly clear, you need to initialize it before you read it.)

This'd be obvious in a debugger.  Learn `cgdb` (on Cygwin or WSL) or try the Oracle Netbeans `C++` download package.  The VS 2017 Community Edition can also work with gcc and cmake (a little less so with straight Makefiles).

```
multiplication[row]=new int[c2];

for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex <c2; colIndex++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <r2; col++)
    {
        multiplication[row][colIndex] = multiplication[row][colIndex] + matrix1[row][col] * matrix2[col][colIndex];
```